# Automatically generate the List of Acronyms

Tags: acronyms, acro

I have a document in which I use the packet `acro`:

```
\usepackage{acro}
\input{./acronyms.tex}
```

Here, in the file `acronyms.tex`, I have all the definitions I want. It works properly when I use the command `\ac{..}` and so on.

I would like to have a page at the beginning of the document with the "List of Acronyms", in the same way of List of Figures or Table.

I have found [this example](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/examples/automatic-acronym-list-in-latex/dzvxfzpsjrmm) but it does not work: if I add the usage of the packet `acronym` I get latex error.

**Question**: is there a way for generating automatically a new page with acronyms by using the `acro`?

The main doc is structured in this way:

```
\include{formatAndDefs}
\graphicspath{{D01_Figures/}}
\begin{document}
\include{A01_TitlePage/TitlePage}
%....other things here

\dominitoc
\begin{spacing}{1.3}
\pagenumbering{roman}
  \cleardoublepage
\include{A02_Acknowledgements/Acknowledgements}
  \cleardoublepage
\include{A03_Abstract/Abstract}
  \cleardoublepage
\include{A03_Abstract/AbstractSpanish}
\tableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
  \cleardoublepage
\listoftables
  \cleardoublepage
\mainmatter

\include{B01_Chapter1/Chapter1}
\include{B02_Chapter2/Chapter2}
\include{B03_Chapter3/Chapter3}
\include{B04_Chapter4/Chapter4}
\include{B05_Chapter5/Chapter5}
\include{B06_Chapter6/Chapter6}
\end{spacing}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

So, in this context, if I use, for example, `\printacronyms', how to generate a new page in a similar way of "List of Figure"?

Edit: if I use the solution proposed in the answer, the result is:

[image]

Comment: Did you already try with `\printacronyms`? To quote from the doumentation: "Printing the whole list of acronyms is easy: just place `\printacronyms` where ever you wantthe list to be."

Comment: nope, try it right now

Comment: If I were to guess than your list of figures uses a `\chapter*` while `\printacronyms` uses `\section*`. But you can change this: `\printacronyms[heading=chapter*]` or maybe `\chapter*{Acronyms} \printacronyms[heading=]`

Comment: In your MWE, there is no printacronyms command. What if you include your acronyms.tex instead of inputting it? Or just do a cleardoublepage before the input like you did for the other lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\printacronyms` command for this. You can specify the name you like with the `name` option (e.g. "List of acronyms", as mentioned in your question). Since your question asks about printing the list on a new page, you can just use `\clearpage` beforehand. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{jpg}
{
    short = JPEG ,
    sort  = jpeg ,
    alt   = JPG ,
    long  = Joint Photographic Experts Group
}
\DeclareAcronym{la}
{
    short        = LA ,
    short-plural = ,
    long         = Los Angeles,
    long-plural  = ,
    class        = city
}

\begin{document}

    I live in \ac{la} and love \ac{jpg}

    \clearpage

    \printacronyms[name = {List of acronyms}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 it works properly. However, it does not generate a page like in the case of List of Figure of List of Table. For instance, it has just generate the Acronyms in the page of List of Table

Comment: @Leos313, could you provide a more detailed [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) in your question? It would be easier to help you.

Comment: question updated with the result

Comment: Your MWE isn't self contained so it's hard to tell you what went wrong. If I add a table and `\listoftables` to the example in my answer, I get the same thing as `\printacronyms`. As @cgnieder pointed out, your issue is likely due to the fact that `\listoftables` uses a chapter in the class you used but we can't know for sure as long as you don't provide an complete example that we can copy/paste and compile.